# How to pass arguments to program in a for loop of a shell script

Tags: bash, shell, for-loop, arguments

I'm having a little trouble implementing a very simple shell script.  I want to run a program with command line inputs 2-100 as one of the program arguments and direct the results to another file, i.e.

```
for (( c=2; c<101; c++))
do
   ./virtmem 100 $c fifo sort2 >> results/FIFOSORT.txt
done
```

But this doesn't quite work because it says fifo isn't a program. Any suggestions?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: I would listen to it, if it thinks "fifo" isn't a program, then it thinks "fifo" isn't a program. That is, what happens if $c is replaced with a constant, say, 2 (which was said to be valid in another comment). I suspect it will be the *same* error making the variable usage a red-herring.

Comment: It would help if you pasted the exact output from the command line. This looks to me like an internal `virtmem` problem.

Comment: Thanks pst and bacchus, virtmem needed to be recompiled and the quotes needed to be around fifo and sort2. Neither one alone worked, thanks a ton.

Answer (score 1):

What is virtmem doing with those args?  If it's trying to run "fifo" as another script, perhaps fifo needs "chmod +x" to make it exec'able?

Comment: Virtmem is a program that takes two integers and two strings as an argument.  The first integer must always be 100, while the second must vary from 2-100 and the results must be recorded.  Fifo and sort2 are just the last two arguments of the program, not other scripts. It's a virtual memory emulator with the first integer as the number of pages and the second as the number of frames. The two strings are the replacement algorithm and the test function.

Answer (score 0):

Try to either do this

`` `./virtmem 100 $c fifo sort2 >> results/FIFOSORT.txt ```

or this

`./virtmem 100 $c "fifo" "sort2" >> results/FIFOSORT.txt`.

I think it will solve your problem.